# Play mp3 file before refer to other page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really need a help, because the are deadline of project tomorrow.
I have one link, for example `<a href="http://somewhere.com" class="lnk">Link</a>`
I have click.mp3 file in root directory.
I want to play it 4 seconds and then refer to somewhere.com
I write something like this but it not works

```
$(function(){ $(".menu_link").click(function(){
                soundClick();
                setTimeout(refFunc($(this).attr('href')),5000);
                return false;
            });   
});   
function soundClick() {
            var audio = new Audio(); 
            audio.src = 'myUrl/click.mp3';
            audio.autoplay = true;
        }
        function refFunc(ref)
        {
            window.location.href = ref;
        }
```

The soundClick function works, I try to autoplay when page reload, it works.
Timeout not working, refer begins immidiatly. Why? I think the logic of code is true. I play sound, wait 5 sec. and refer page. But 5 secs not show himselves.

Comment: Unless this is for an assignment, please don't do it. Unexpected sounds in webpages are just about the most annoying thing in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       $(".menu_link").click(function(){
            soundClick();
            var ref = $(this).attr('href');
            setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.href = ref;
            },5000);
            return false;
        });  
       function soundClick() {
           var audio = new Audio(); 
           audio.src = 'myUrl/click.mp3';
           audio.autoplay = true;
       }
```